# Alerts dialog not working after SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2019 migration

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019, migration, sharepoint-alerts

I have a SharePoint 2019 site. It was migrated from SharePoint 2010 version.

However after migration, alert dialog in the ribbon is visible and active but no response on clicking, the modal dialog does not appear. The page does not show any error in the browser console.

Comment: Anything in the diagnostic logs or Event Viewer on the server(s) when it is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

If the issue occurs in classic experience of SharePoint server 2019, please switch to modern experience to compare the result:

[image]

In addition, please help to confirm if all users occur the same issue on different libraries.